# Count of each number where the cell to the right is 1 number higher in an 8 column, 25 row grid

Tags: google-sheets

Table:

```
1  2  3  5  6  8  9 11
2  3  6  7  9 10 11 12
1  2  4  5  6  9 11 14
```

Output:

```
1 2: 2
2 3: 2
3 4: 0
4 5: 1
5 6: 2
6 7: 1
7 8: 0
8 9: 1
9 10: 1
10 11: 1
11 11: 1
12 13: 0
```

I've tried countif w/ AND, countifs, vlookup, filter, as well as various methods of concat. I haven't found any method that seems to get me in the ballpark. I don't think Sheets has any function similar to Excel's (or was it 123?) @cellpointer {RIGHT}. I'm just looking for a starting point as nothing I've tried has gotten me in the right direction.

The closest I've gotten is

```
=AND(countif($K$20:$R$512, $AL3), countif($K$20:$R$512, $AM3))
```

[Where AL3 = 1 and AM3 = 2] (repeated down in secondary table to capture count for each combination)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I've been at this for two days and have crawled through Sheets function help, done about 50 google searches and tried just about every function that looked like it might work. I keep getting hung up on: value of the cell to the immediate right has to be left+1.

Comment: May I try to clarify? The "table" represents a sample of the 8 column x 25 row grid. The "output" displays the counts. "Output" has three numbers: the first is a partial list of the unique numbers in the table, the second is the first number plus 1, the third number is the count of the number of instances of the values in columns 1 and 2 appearing side-by-side in the table. For example, 1:2, appears in the first row and third row, so the count = 2; 3:4 never appears as a combination in any row so the count is zero. Is this an accurate description?

Comment: @Tedinoz, your assessment is the same one I reached.

Comment: @SBost, I can conceptualize how I would go about this; but the easiest way for us to share test and share solutions will be if you will include a link to a spreadsheet that includes a sample 8x25 grid of numbers as well as your expected results manually entered where you would like the formula to produce them. Just be sure, when creating such a link, that you set the permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Thank you, Tedinoz & Erik.  Here is a link to the sample table.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zj6oqXvaNjBeiO6PgTJDBvgaPd2wfo9I-jr6cEHR9M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the number 13 coming from in the output, please clarify.

Comment: The numbers in the 2 left columns of the output table are pre-created, while the 3rd column is the calculated count of each occurence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a table like this:

```
001|002 17
002|003 17
```

...with this formula:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    flatten( 
      if( 
        A2:G26 + 1 = B2:H26, 
        text(A2:G26, "000") & "|" & text(B2:H26, "000"), 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ), 
    "select Col1, count(Col1) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label count(Col1) '' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

To split the `001|002` into 1 and 2, use this:

`=arrayformula( { iferror(split(J2:J, "|", false, true)), K2:K } )`

Note that the results will omit number pairs that do not appear in the data. To add zeros for number pairs that do not appear in the data, use this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      M2:O; 
      sequence( max(A2:H26) - min(A2:H26), 1, min(A2:H26) ),  
      sequence( max(A2:H26) - min(A2:H26), 1, min(A2:H26) + 1 ), 
      0 * sequence( max(A2:H26) - min(A2:H26) )
    }, 
    "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1, Col2 
     label sum(Col3) '' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

See new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zj6oqXvaNjBeiO6PgTJDBvgaPd2wfo9I-jr6cEHR9M/edit#gid=1557549251) sheet in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: This looks great! Thank you! My only problem now is that an occurrence of zero isn't trivial. Each possible combination is important to the overall data analysis. I can probably use this as a temporary table and copy the "count" output into a static table with all number pairs represented. :)

Comment: You can use another formula to add zero counts for number pairs that do not appear in the data. Edited the answer and the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zj6oqXvaNjBeiO6PgTJDBvgaPd2wfo9I-jr6cEHR9M/edit#gid=1557549251) to show how.